# Recycler View error

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating Recycler View.

Here is `MainActivity` Code:

```
package com.example.nemes.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

// set the adapter
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        prepareMovieData();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    private void prepareMovieData() {
        Movie movie = new Movie("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Action & Adventure", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Inside Out", "Animation, Kids & Family", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens", "Action", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Shaun the Sheep", "Animation", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("The Martian", "Science Fiction & Fantasy", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Mission: Impossible Rogue Nation", "Action", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Up", "Animation", "2009");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Star Trek", "Science Fiction", "2009");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("The LEGO Movie", "Animation", "2014");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Iron Man", "Action & Adventure", "2008");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Aliens", "Science Fiction", "1986");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Chicken Run", "Animation", "2000");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Back to the Future", "Science Fiction", "1985");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Raiders of the Lost Ark", "Action & Adventure", "1981");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Goldfinger", "Action & Adventure", "1965");
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Guardians of the Galaxy", "Science Fiction & Fantasy", "2014");
        movieList.add(movie);

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And Adapter class:

```
package com.example.nemes.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Movie> moviesList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, year, genre;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
        }
    }


    public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> moviesList) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
        holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
        holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }
}
```

My problem is - when i launch app all okay, I see movies and info

Here is screen:

[image]

But when I scroll activity, I have this

[image: Error screen]

It turns bigger.

Where is error?

Thank's for help.

**UPDATE**

Here is `movie_list_row` layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textColor="@color/title"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/year"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the `movie_list_row` layout ?

Comment: Done. I updated post@L.Swifter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `movie_list_row`, change your `RelativeLayout`'s height to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Or set an exact value like `100dip`.

Comment: I  will try now this

Comment: It helps. Thank's dude

Answer (score 0):

In your `movie_list_row` just change the `layout_height` of `relative layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
              android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="vertical">
```